# How to extract values from the WTForm fields in Python?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I built this simple webpage with Flask.

[image]

Instead of using HTML widgets such as  for the form, I used the Flask WTForm library which allows you to write the form widgets from the Python code. Here is my Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from wtforms import Form,StringField, SubmitField
from flask.views import View, MethodView

app = Flask(__name__)

class SquareForm(Form):
    side = StringField('Side of the square')
    button = SubmitField("Calculate")


class HomePage(MethodView):

    def get(self):
        return render_template('index2.html', square_form=square_form)

    def post(self):
        square_area = square_form.side.data * 2
        return render_template('index2.html', square_form=square_form, result = square_area)

# Create a view function for HomePage class
home_page = HomePage.as_view('home_page')
app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=home_page)
app.add_url_rule('/result', view_func=home_page, methods=['POST'])
square_form = SquareForm()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And this is my index.html code:

```
<form method="POST" action="/result">
    {{ square_form.side.label }}: {{ square_form.side() }}
    {{square_form.button()}}
    {{result}}
</form>
```

I run the code and enter `5` in the HTML input box, but I get an error:

```
  File "/Users/folder/main.py", line 18, in post
    square_area = square_form.side.data * 2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Obviously, the TypeError occurs because `square_form.side.data` is `None`. I expect `square_form.side.data` to be `'5'` instead. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the form needed to be initialized inside the post method with a `request.form` argument:

```
from flask import request
def post(self):
    square_form = SquareForm(request.form)
    square_area = square_form.side.data * 2
    return render_template('index2.html', square_form=square_form, result = square_area)
```